# cannot set the icon to the tabspec

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I am sure i have the pictures and xml set up already. I ran my app on the android emulator, it just pop-up a windows showed that the app stopped running. But after deleting the icon part including `res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon1)`, `res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon2)` and `res.‌​getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon3)` the app works fine.

```
public class ActionBar extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TabHost th;
TextView showResult;
long start, stop;
Resources res;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar);
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();
    Button newTab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddTab);
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
    showResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    newTab.setOnClickListener(this);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tab1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("Stop Watch", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon1));
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tab2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("Add Tab", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon2));
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tab3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("Blank", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon3));
    res = getResources();
    th.addTab(specs);
}
```

Comment: @SimonH the app stopped when i run it,but after deleting the icon part including res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon1),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon2),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon3),the app works fine

Comment: i ran it on the android emulator,it just pop-up a windows showed that the app stopped running

Comment: thank you so much it did work!!one more question,the icons show up on my version 2.2 but on the emulator version 4.2,it only have the texts ,why?

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward thing that I can see is that you should define `res = getResources();` before using the `res` variable at all the three places. Right now you are using it, before defining it and that might be throwing an exceptioon. Do something like:

```
//....
res = getResources();
specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
specs.setIndicator("Stop Watch", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon1));
th.addTab(specs);
specs = th.newTabSpec("tab2");
specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
specs.setIndicator("Add Tab", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon2));
th.addTab(specs);
specs = th.newTabSpec("tab3");
specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
specs.setIndicator("Blank", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon3));
//....
```

Also please post the LogCat information if you need further help. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Xiu Tiger Yi: What error does it give on emulator for 4.2 android? Can yu pos the LogCat ?